# How to change the behaviour of touchscreen in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse, touchpad, touchscreen

I have a touchscreen connected to my Ubuntu 22.04 PC. When I move my finger across screen, the cursor moves with it, but the left mouse button isn't being pressed at the same time. That is, it's e.g. impossible to select multiple items in a directory by just moving the cursor across them. To achieve that I need to double-click first.

How to change that? I have my own app for gesture recognition and it just follows cursor when the left mouse button is pressed. This will be the only app running on this PC ever, so I don't need any extra functionality I will loose by changing this behavior.

I've found that I should disable or enable tapping in system settings, but I see "no touchpad found" there.

```
sms@home-sms:~$ xinput list-props 20
Device 'WaveShare WS170120':
        Device Enabled (156):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (158): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Calibration Matrix (692):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Calibration Matrix Default (693):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (269):     1, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (270):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (271):        0, 0
        Device Node (272):      "/dev/input/event16"
        Device Product ID (273):        3823, 5

sms@home-sms:~$ less /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0eef Product=0005 Version=0110
N: Name="WaveShare WS170120"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/0003:0EEF:0005.000D/input/input31
U: Uniq=        fA1818^UL789
H: Handlers=mouse2 event16 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800001000003
B: MSC=20
```